# How do I remove the export loader in the Banuba Video Editor?

Tags: android, ios, video, export

I do not see the info on how to remove the export loader from my Video Editor.

I tried looking on your website but did not find any information on the subject matter.
I need links with detailed instructions if possible, please.

Answer (score -1):

Feel free to check out the following guides, as they describe all the options possible for configuring the export styles for both platforms:

**Android Export Configuration Guide** - https://github.com/Banuba/ve-sdk-android-integration-sample/blob/main/mddocs/guide_export.md

**iOS Export Configuration Guide** - https://github.com/Banuba/ve-sdk-ios-integration-sample/blob/main/mdDocs/guide_export.md

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. However, we discourage link-only answers; please either answer here, on the site (a link to official documentation _in addition_ to an actual solution for background is fine, and encouraged), or refrain from answering. Once you earn enough reputation, you will be able to leave comments if you don't want to post complete answers.